# How do I integrate this expression with the residue theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm trying to find the value of the following expression using the residue theorem...

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2x)}{x^2+4}dx$$
My attempt is as follows: I've separated the denominator into two fractions
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2x)}{(x+j2)(x-j2)}dx$$
Now multiply by each fraction to get the residue at both poles and using Euler's identities...

$$\frac{\cos(2x)}{(x-j2)},\ x=-j2 =>\frac{1}{-j4}\frac{e^4+e^{-4}}{2}$$
$$\frac{\cos(2x)}{(x+j2)},\ x=j2 =>\frac{1}{j4}\frac{e^{-4}+e^{-4}}{2}$$

Add then together and multiply by $j2\pi$

$$j2\pi[\frac{1}{j4}\frac{e^{-4}+e^{-4}}{2} - \frac{1}{j4}\frac{e^4+e^{-4}}{2}]$$
$$\frac{\pi}{2}(\frac{e^{-4}-e^{4}}{2})$$
This is different from the answer I get in Wolfram Alpha which is $\frac{\pi}{4e^4}$. Can anyone spot my error or misunderstanding of how the theorem works?

Comment: The residue theorem holds for integrals over closed curves, and only involves the residues at the enclosed poles.

Comment: You should draw the curve you want to integrate into the plane and think about what happens when you let the Radius of the curve go to infinity.

Comment: Hint: $\exp(2iz)$ is small away from zero in which half plane? (upper/lower)

Comment: Thanks @BrevanEllefsen, I've chosen the upper half and integrated on a semi-circle and got the correct answer. Could you explain why my curve doesn't need to cover all of the poles in the denominator?

Comment: @Eind997 The residue theorem holds for all closed paths. The trick is to choose a path over one of whose segments the integral is the one you're ultimately interested in, and such that you can compute the integral over the remainder (usually because the integral goes to 0 when you increase the size of the path). Such a path may enclose all, some or none of the poles of the integrand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos (2x)}{x^2+4}\,d x=\frac1{2}\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{\cos (2x)}{x^2+4}\,d x=\frac1{2}\operatorname{Re}\left[\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{e^{i2x}}{x^2+4}\,d x\right]
$$
Now observe that $|e^{iz}|=e^{\operatorname{Re}(iz)}=e^{-\operatorname{Im}(z)}$, so $\lim_{\operatorname{Im}(z)\to +\infty }|e^{iz}|=0$, and use a contour $\gamma_R :=\alpha _R\oplus \beta_R$ defined by
$$
\alpha _R:[-R,R]\to \mathbb{C},\, t\mapsto t\\
\beta _R:[0,\pi]\to \mathbb{C},\, t\mapsto Re^{it}
$$

Then you find that
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos (2x)}{x^2+4}\,d x&=\frac1{2}\operatorname{Re}\left[\lim_{R\to +\infty }\int_{\gamma _R}\frac{e^{i2z}}{z^2+4}\,d z\right]\\&=\frac1{2}\operatorname{Re}\left[ 2\pi i\cdot \operatorname{res}\left(\frac{e^{i2z}}{z^2+4}, z=2i\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4e^{4}}
\end{align*}
$$

as $\lim_{R\to +\infty }\int_{\beta _R}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+4}\,d z=0$.

Comment: Thanks @Masacroso that makes sense now. Please could you explain why you only need to include one pole in your contour as opposed to both?

Comment: There's no rule that says you need to include all the poles. The goal is to just construct a contour such that it includes the interval that you are integrating on. @Eind997